# Recieving HTML file as responce instead of JSON Object through get request

Tags: android, html, json, android-studio

I am developing an android app where user logs on to his/her account. After logging in I will receive XSRF token and Laravel Session Id to recognise the specific user. I have to send these tokens for every request I send to the API's to get the appropriate information. But when I am sending the required details as shown in the image, I am getting HTMl file as response instead of getting JSON Object. I was seriously stuck at this problem. Correct Solution may take forward the whole app.

```
 class RegisterConnection extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject> {
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        JSONObject output = new JSONObject();
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 5000); //Timeout Limit
        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(statsURL);
            get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            CookieStore store = new BasicCookieStore();
            BasicClientCookie cookie1 = new BasicClientCookie("XSRF-TOKEN", XSRF);
            BasicClientCookie cookie2 = new BasicClientCookie("laravel_session", laravel);
            store.addCookie(cookie1);
            store.addCookie(cookie2);
            client.setCookieStore(store);

            response = client.execute(get);



            if(response!=null){
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String resultstring = Utilities.convertStreamToString(in);
                Log.i("Result1", resultstring);
                output = new JSONObject(resultstring);
                Log.i("Result2", output.toString());
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                output.put("sai","error");
                Log.i("MainActivity", output.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

These are the server requirements

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCzM9.jpg

This is the Output received

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcx2b.jpg

Comment: Why are you asking us about what your server is returning without showing anything about the server?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your Android client code. 
You are getting HTML from the server so the main reason could be that your Laravel server is rendering the views and sending you back html instead of JSON. 
 Instead of rendering the views on the server, you should send JSON response on your Laravel server side.

Answer (score 0):

Add Jsoup dependency in your gradle file
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("http://imgur.com/IB5AEcT");  
Elements el = doc.select("button");
Log.i("..........",""+el.attr("data-invite-details"));
```

Jsoup tutorial
http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html